# Which of the following functions is one-to-one?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Q: A function $f:A\rightarrow b:x \mapsto  f(x)$ is a one-to-one function is for all $x,y\in A$ it holds that: if $x\neq y$, then $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Determine which of the following functions is one-to-one.

a) $f:N\times N\rightarrow N:(n,m) \mapsto m+n $

b) $f:N\times N\rightarrow N:(n,m) \mapsto mn $

c) $f:N\times N\rightarrow N:(n,m) \mapsto 3^m5^n $

d) $f:N\times N\rightarrow N:(n,m) \mapsto m^n $

e) $f:N\times N\rightarrow N:(n,m) \mapsto 2^{m+n} $

The answer is supposed to be C. First of all, I have no idea what the expression $f:A\rightarrow b:x \mapsto  f(x)$ means. Is A the domain and B the codomain of $f(x)$?

Also, what does $f:N\times N\rightarrow N:(n,m) \mapsto$ mean? Does it mean that A is composed of the multiplication of two integers?

Could someone please help me with determining which one is a one-to-one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer each of your queries

$f:A \to b:x \to f(x)$ is stating that $f$ is a function from domain $A$ to co-domain $b$, such that $x \in A$ and $f(x) \in b$

$N \times N$ is the cartesian product of the set of natural numbers - each ordered pair $(n_1, n_2)$ is considered here (for example, $(3,5)$ is an element of $N \times N$, and is different from $(5,3)$

Now, the easiest way to answer this question is to see if you can come up with counter-examples. For the first two it is fairly obvious - just consider two elements in the domain $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ - though they are distinct points in $A$, they map to the same point $(x+y, xy)$ for both of them, the same can be extended to the last one

Now for d), again it's easy to come up with a counter -example: just consider a number like $64$, it can be represented as $2^6$ or $4^3$ - both correspond to unique points in $A$ - $(2,6), (4,3)$

Now all that remains is c) - assume that there exists two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ such that $f(x_,y_1) = f(x_2,y_2)$

$$\implies 3^{x_1}5^{y_1} = 3^{x_2}5^{y_2}$$
$$\implies 3^{x_1-x_2}5^{y_1-y_2} = 1 = 3^05^0$$

Since 3 and 5 are co-prime, the only way to express $1$ as a product of powers of $3$,$5$ is as above, hence you get $x_1 = x_2, y_1=y_2$ which means the points are coincident

Comment: What a spectacular answer! Thank you so much for explaining every detail yet making it so concise! I now understand the concept and the reason why C is the only one-to-one function.